# Does the input buffer gets cleared after scanf reads?

Tags: c, scanf, buffer

Does the input buffer gets cleared after `scanf` reads?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d", &a);//I inputted 3
    scanf("%d", &b);//I inputted 4
}
```

So when I gave the input `4` was `3` present in the input buffer?

Comment: Is your input `"4\n3\n"` or `"4 3\n"`? Also which mode is your tty in(raw, line, etc)?

Comment: The buffer is read and discarded up to the first character that stops the conversion, which remains in the buffer, along with anything after that.

Comment: The answers below are a bit simplified.  Your program and you typing into your console are asynchronous parallel processes.  The OS keeps a queue of characters typed at the keyboard and programs consume them.  The interface you are coding to is C streams. Until `scanf` returns with a status, it's impossible to say exactly what happened, without a debugging the entire system.

Comment: Is this an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?  Are you trying to diagnose unexpected behavior of your program?

Comment: @jwdonahue the question is simple as well (and very focused). I cannot guess if OP is asking it because it expects the first char to remain in the buffer or not..

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, well the OP seems to have found their answer.

Comment: @jwdonahue so at least one answer (not mine :) ) wasn't too simplified. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when I gave the input 4 was 3 present in the input buffer?

No, the 3 was consumed.

You cannot re-read it (as int or otherwise).

If you input `"3<enter>"` the 3 is consumed and the buffer contains just the `"<enter>"`. You then type `"4<enter>"` which is added to the buffer. The 2nd scanf (*) consumes the initial enter and the 4 leaving `"<enter>"` for the next input operation.

(*) the conversion specifier `"%d"` skips optional leading whitespace and (tries to) converts the rest of the input to integer (if no errors occur).

Answer (score 0):

> So when I gave the input 4 was 3 present in the input buffer?

No, it wasn't.

[`scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) reads (and consumes) from the standard input until a match the specified format (in your case an integer) is found. That format is converted and consumed as well.